# Setting up WAMP Server on Windows XP

Tags: mysql, apache, webserver, wamp, windows-xp

I want a WAMP Server on my windows XP machine (Apache, MySQL, PHP) but all the ones I know of don't support XP (WAMP, XAMPP, Bitnami etc).

Are there any others that I can use?

Ps. I'm avoiding EasyPHP as I have tried it already and had constant problems. Also, Xampp might be compatible but it comes with MariaDb and I need MySQL.

Comment: MariaDb and MySQL are almost same basically. The queries you run on MySQL will run on MariaDb also. Please check it, I will prefer you to use XAMPP

Comment: I'm required to use MySQL as I'm setting up the server for a company so I don't have a choice. As stated in my answer below, I found an older version of XAMPP which works with Windows XP and it comes with MySQL so it's all good!

Comment: Newer versions of WAMPServer/XAMPP wont run on XP because the newer versions are compiled with newer versions of Visual Studio. The C/C++ runtime libraries required for code compiled with these newer versions of VS will now install on XP (its a microsoft decision) So therefore APache and PHP wont run. The last version of WAMPServer that will run on XP is [version 2.4 downloadable here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the ideal solution is to either:

**1.** use a newer operating system

**2.** Or switch to Linux! (I can't do that because I'm using a work computer)

The alternative I've found is to install an older, compatible version of XAMPP server (Version 1.8.2) which can be downloaded from here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.2/